# Execute list of eloquent methods/calls in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a routine that reads a list of eloquent commands (from an input to the route/controller or via a file):

eg:

```
Product::where('code', '=', 'ABC123')->update(array('price' => 123.45));
Product::where('code', '=', 'ABC246')->update(array('price' => 222.99));
```

How do I get Laravel to execute these, as if it was building them itself?

I know that I can use PHP's `eval()` method, but only as a last resort. The commands being passed through are generated by another internal system of ours, so there is no problems with this being exploited, however am hoping for a better option than `eval()`.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to do it one by one in a loop

```
$products = Product::where('code', '=', 'ABC123')->get();
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $product->price() = '123.45';
    $product->save();
}
```

Comment: On the right track, but the issue is getting PHP to evaluate the string and run it. I can use eval() but I don't really want to have to resort to that.